# Quack overflow on our site

Tags: discussion

Friends,

Some of you might have noticed the presence of a yellow duck in the lower right corner of our site, acting as the fabled Clippy bloke from the Office family. I know there has been *a lot* of duck-related content in this community lately, to the point of people getting justifiably annoyed by them. Just for the sake of not raising the public outrage any more, and also for the sheer fact that I do not enjoy being chased by an angry mob carrying pitchforks and torches (or any other pointed sticks), I must point out that this duck is not particularly related to us or the inner jokes of this community. It's a global April Fools thingy, and incidentally they had chosen a duck. In short, quoting a very wise bloke

## It is not my fault.

`:)`

Comment: It's not your fault, nor that of any of the other resident ducks.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: yes. `:)`

Comment: we blame you anyway

Comment: I will attack you with a banana, however ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: where's the 16ton weight? `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Be careful with such requests  :-P

Comment: How do we know that this is really you and not the duck at the corner? ... It's looking at me... I am scar....

Comment: good thing you posted this because I had arrived on meta precisely to complain `;-)` ... but I saw your post, so despite the rampaging duckification I will grant you a +1 ...

Comment: @percusse: oh nooooooo, sir! Come back! The evil duck has taken sir!

Comment: @jfbu: thanks. `:)` I know there's a *lot* of duck things in here, to the point of being a nuisance. But this time I am not the one to blame. `:)`

Comment: Ducks? Thanks. (Obscure reference is obscure.)

Answer (score 13):

I don't believe you. I believe you run the whole duck show on all of the SE network (which doesn't have to be a bad thing, btw).

Answer (score 12):

It is a wonderful coincidence. If I could, I'd happily keep the duck even past April Fools' day

Comment: You can. See the [quack.js for your language](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/quack.en.js), or a [working archive](https://unikong.github.io/quackoverflow/).